# Temporary individual list or view for users

Tags: 2013, javascript, list-view, jsom

I want some kind of dynamically created List for every visiting user in SP 2013.

The data lives in multiple lists and I want it to be aggregated in the target list/view.

When a user visits the site, I want to show him/her a new List or View containing the aggregated list items he is allowed to see. The desired list items can be determined and created via their IDs (the lists with the source data are connected via LookupFields), so getting the items and their fields would just be a simple query containing a join over the lists with the source data.

When the user exits the site the List or View should disappear.

I think creating a new list for every visiting user is a really bad idea.

So I want to have a custom temporary list for each user for the time he visits the site. It should be a "real" sharepoint list with all its functionalities.

I only have JSOM to realize that (Sharepoint hosted add-in). Maybe there are any elements Sharepoint provides to create such a temoprary list/view?

**Edit:**
I changed the whole text to make the problem I'm facing more clear. Sorry for the bad first description.

Comment: Assuming you have a list containing all the content, you could grant them permissions on each item in the list. So if the list contains 100 items but you are using their username or usergroup to grant them view permissions for that item, when they view the list they should only see those items. If you provide us with more information on where the content you want them to see lives, then we should be able to compose an answer.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry. I forgot that. The content lives in multiple other lists. This content should then be aggregated and merged into the temporary list.

Comment: @RayHogan Unique permissions on list item level are bad design and should be avoided because of performance and maintainability reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do elevated permissions with JSOM (all code runs with their account) so if you (no, the current user) need to Create a List they need proper permissions.

You can create a Personal View on an existing list with JSOM.

I say ditch the JSOM idea and use Search (which is security trimmed)

You don't specify a version. On 2013/Online built a nice Display Template.

Comment: Ok, I see that my description of the problem was really bad. I'll edit the question so that my problem is more clear to describe it as how I meant it..